# Pass variable to default codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have my codeigniter setup with a default controller.  It's accessible as follows:

```
site.com/index.php
```

But it's actually:

```
site.com/project/index
```

Where index is the default function.

I would like to do the following:

```
site.com/project7362
```

But it actually wants:

```
site.com/project/index/project7362
```

Where project name is a variable that is pass into the index function.  But by default it looks for project-name as a controller.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Essentially what I'm hoping to accomplish is to pass a variable directly after the domain name.  A user may create a project, and I want that project to be accessible at domain.com/project_id

Comment: Hello Adam, what is name of your controller that you are trying to use? Please also edit project and project-name more clearly so it is understandable what you want to achieve.

Comment: The name of my controller is "project".  Do my edits make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Essentially what I'm hoping to accomplish is to pass a variable
>   directly after the domain name. A user may create a project, and I
>   want that project to be accessible at domain.com/project_id"

so another way to do this would be to have it like.

```
domain.com/project/id
```

this will give you much more flexibility later in your routes for adding different features.
in config/routes:

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/view/$1';
```

in your project controller

```
    function view($id) {

    // clean it
    $id = htmlspecialchars($id) ;

   if ( ! $project = $this->members->returnProjectBy($id) {

       $this->showNoResultsFor($id) ; } 

   else { $this->show($project) ;  } 

   }
```

**OR -- another way to do this** would be to put your defined routes first, and then have project be last (because it requires searching on whatever is there)

```
$route['home'] = 'page/home'; 
$route['contact'] = 'contact'; 
// etc etc so you first define your hard coded routes, and then if its not any of those
// you do a search on whatever the value is to find a project 
$route['(:any)'] = 'project/view/$1';
```

so then your link could be

```
domain.com/id
```